# How to pick lines containg numbers in given positions on the line with python

Tags: python

I have a text with the following structure:

```
 LINE LINK DEFINITION NUMBER      337 ID =  44015945


 SPW. NB.     SPW. ID.      LENGTH     ELEM.   MAT-ID         X         Y         Z      NODES

      673       673.00    .357E+01 44013671   4400341  0.323E+03-0.448E+03 0.485E+03   44020544 
                                   44002527   4400331  0.326E+03-0.450E+03 0.484E+03   44020545 
     1502       673.01    .558E+01 44013671   4400341  0.323E+03-0.451E+03 0.485E+03   44022202 
                                   44002527   4400331  0.329E+03-0.450E+03 0.484E+03   44022203 
      674       674.00    .355E+01 44013671   4400341  0.323E+03-0.448E+03 0.480E+03   44020546 
                                   44002516   4400331  0.325E+03-0.450E+03 0.479E+03   44020547 
     1503       674.01    .561E+01 44013671   4400341  0.323E+03-0.451E+03 0.480E+03   44022204 
                                   44002516   4400331  0.328E+03-0.450E+03 0.479E+03   44022205
```

Now I would like to write in a new file only those lines, which contains numbers in a given position on the line - for example the following lines:

```
      676       676.00    .355E+01 44007503   4400341  0.322E+03-0.448E+03 0.475E+03   44020550 
                                   44002516   4400331  0.325E+03-0.450E+03 0.474E+03   44020551
```

Any ideas would be highly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**An update**

[Drago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2733168/drago) you may want to use Python filter() function. It is efficient and elegant. The function stores results in memory. Because your solution stores the whole file in memory I assume this is acceptable.

filter() is [a built in Python function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). It takes two arguments: an iterable and a selector function and creates another iterable (list, tuple or string). filter() applies the selector to every element of the input sequence. The returned sequence contains elements from the input sequence for which the selector evaluates to true. It is roughly equivalent to

```
for object in sequence:
   if selector(object):
      result.append(object)
```

File is an iterable object hence it can be filtered. As a selector you can simply use something like your is_number function where string indices are hard coded but I made it more flexible by defining a function that takes indices as parameters and returns a selector. Note that selector accepts a single argument.

Here is a solution

```
def is_number(s):
    """ From your solution. """
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def func(i1, i2):
    return lambda str: is_number(str[i1:i2].strip())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = []
    with open('in.txt') as fin:
       result = filter(func(0,10), fin)
    with open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
        for s in result:
            fout.write(s)
```

**Initial answer**

Here is a rough plan for you:

1. Read the file
2. Split lines into lists
3. Filter out lines matching your criteria
4. Write the resulting list to a new file

Some code to get you started:

A function that returns a decision function. This will be used later on in a filter function. It creates a function that takes an argument to an indexable object and returns true or false value.

```
def func(idx, number):
  return lambda arg: arg[idx] == number
```

Open file and read it splitting each line. This needs more work. You will need to take care of your file format., e.g. read numbers properly, ignore non data lines.

```
input = open('file name', 'r')
listoflists = []
for line in input:
  list = line.split(' ') # an example of splitting with space separator
  listoflists.append(list)
```

Filter data using built-in Python function

```
idx = 1
number = 10
result = filter(func(idx, number), listoflists)
```

Write to an output file. You may want to format it like you need.

```
out = open('file name', 'w')
for l in result:
  out.write(l)
```

Close your files...

```
input.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Dmitri, 

thank you for the time and the answer. I found in the meantime a solution. For sure not the best but it does what I wanted

### a function to check if a string contains float number
def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
        
with open(inputfile2) as f1:
    with open('ELEM_ID_and_proj_points_coordinates.txt', 'w') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if (is_number(line[0:13].strip()) and ...):
                f2.write(lines[i])

Comment: You are welcome. I updated my answer for completeness. Cheers.

Comment: Could you please clarify the filter function

Comment: OK, see in the answer